# How to compare between two sources data in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, compare, pymysql

I have large datasets from 2 sources, one is a huge text file (as a new data) and the other coming from a database (MySQL) (as a historical data). How to compare them to figure out the differences (get only new and modified records). I intended to read each one line in the text file and compare with the data in MySQL.

The text file (demo.txt):

```
0001|NAME1|A1
0002|NAME2|A2
0003|NAME3|A3
0004|NAME4|A4
0005|NAME5|A1
```

The data in MySQL:

```
id   |   name   |   address
----------------------------
0001 |   NAME1  |   A1
----------------------------
0002 |   NAME2  |   A2
----------------------------
0003 |   NAME3  |   A4
----------------------------
0004 |   NAME4  |   A4
----------------------------
```

The expected result:

```
0003|NAME3|A4
0005|NAME5|A1
```

And this is my effort:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='password',
                             db='test',
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
myfile = open("demo.txt","r")
lines = myfile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    data=line.split('|')
    sql_query = """SELECT * FROM HistoricalTable WHERE id = {}""".format(data[0])
    check=cursor.execute(sql_query)
    result=cursor.fetchall()

    if check>=1:
        for i in result:
            if data[0]==i['id'] and data[1]==i['name'] and data[2]==i['address']:
                print("Ignore")
            else:
                print(line)
                break
    else:
        print(line)
```

And I know this is not the best way and will take a lot of time! So Please could I have any suggestion?

Comment: How do you want to find duplicates? By **id**? By **name**? In other words is "0001|NAME1" _equals_ to "0001|NAME2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your questions

I can identify two questions:
- A problem of optimisation,
- A technical question about data set comparison.

#### About optimisation

It is best to have a working program, than an optimised one which doesn’t work perfectly.
So, you may focus on developing something functional, and then optimize it.

Anyway, if you want to find duplicates in two dataset, you'll need at least one data set in memory unless your data sets have some intrinsic properties which allow further optimisation (for instance, I think of ordering).

#### About finding duplicates

For instance, the smaller data set can be loaded in an *iterable* (for instance a `list`) and the second one ca be iterated from file/database, using a generator function.

Here is a demo:

```
# data1 in memory
data1 = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']


# data2 produced by a generator
def item_data2():
    for item in ['a', 'd', 'e', 'c']:
        yield item


duplicates = [x for x in item_data2() if x in data1]
# -> ['a', 'd', 'c']
```

### Some best practices

#### Reading a CSV file

To read CSV files, you can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library. In your specific case, you can use a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

```
import csv
import io
import os
import pprint

delimiter = '|'
header = "id|name|address".split(delimiter)

data_dir = "path/to/data/directory"

csv_path = os.path.join(data_dir, "source1.csv")

with io.open(csv_path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, header, delimiter=delimiter)
    for entry in reader:
        pprint.pprint(entry)

# ->
# OrderedDict([('id', '0001'), ('name', 'NAME1'), ('address', 'A1')])
# OrderedDict([('id', '0002'), ('name', 'NAME2'), ('address', 'A2')])
# OrderedDict([('id', '0003'), ('name', 'NAME3'), ('address', 'A3')])
# OrderedDict([('id', '0004'), ('name', 'NAME4'), ('address', 'A4')])
# OrderedDict([('id', '0005'), ('name', 'NAME5'), ('address', 'A1')])
```

#### Indexing entries by **id**

If you want to compare data which has the same **id**, you can store the data in a mapping which associates the **id** and the other files:

```
data_mapping = {}
with io.open(csv_path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, header, delimiter=delimiter)
    for entry in reader:
        data_id = entry.pop('id')
        data_mapping[data_id] = entry
```

#### Querying the database

For the database, you can iterate over each records instead of fetching all records: you can use `fetchone` instead. But, actually, you can use the cursor as an iterator.

Here is a demo:

```
import pymysql


connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='password',
                             db='test',
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Using the cursor as iterator
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM HistoricalTable")
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Really helpful! Thanks a lot!